# Multiplication in .htaccess

Tags: regex, multiplication, algebra

I have the following two lines in my .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /page/2 /questions?start=12
Redirect 301 /page/3 /questions?start=24
```

I was wondering if it is possible to reduce this to a single line, using something like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /page/([0-9]+) /questions?start=12*($1 - 1)
```

So my question is, how to implement the algebra inside `/questions?start=12*($1 - 1)` ?

Comment: You cannot do scripting  in `mod_alias` or `mod_rewrite` modules.

Comment: Ok thanks. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform mathematical operations in a regex. However you could use a rewrite map to accomplish this, see the Apache Documentation for [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteMap).